# filebeat makes a lot of I/O

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, elk, filebeat

We have filebeat on few servers that is writeing to elasticsearch. We can see that it is doing a lot of writes:

```
  PID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
  353 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    4.52 K/s  0.00 %  0.55 % [jbd2/nvme0n1p1-]
18688 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s    5.85 K/s  0.00 %  0.02 % nginx: worker process
18689 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s    7.18 K/s  0.00 %  0.01 % nginx: worker process
 1304 be/4 root        0.00 B/s   10.37 K/s  0.00 %  0.01 % filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/sha~t -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat
 1162 be/4 proxy       0.00 B/s  272.37 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % (logfile-daemon) /var/log/squid/access.log
```

I have noticed that writes are related to:

```
/var/lib/filebeat/registry
```

and

```
/var/lib/filebeat/registry.new
```

Number of IO operation hurts us on small EBS volumes on EC2 instances.

[Here is IOPS chart from CloudWatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpdtO.png) We have turned on filebeat on 4/6. Before that the chart was flat.

Filebeat config:

```
filebeat.modules:
- module: m-custom
  app:
    prospector:
      fields.class: "m-app"
      fields.env: "live"
  search:
    prospector:
      fields.class: "m-search"
      fields.env: "live"
  img:
    prospector:
      fields.class: "m-img"
      fields.env: "live"
  deploy:
    prospector:
      fields.class: "m-deployment"
      fields.env: "live"
  s3-backup:
    prospector:
      fields.class: "m-s3-backup"
      fields.env: "live"

filebeat.modules:
    - module: system
  syslog:
    enabled: true
    prospector:
      exclude_lines: [" rsyslog-m-log ", " m-log "]
      fields.class: "m-syslog"
      fields.env: "live"

- module: nginx
  access:
    enabled: true
    var.pipeline: with_plugins
    var.paths: [ "/var/log/nginx/*.log", "/var/log/nginx/*.log.1" ]

    prospector:
      fields.class: "m-nginxacc"
      fields.env: "live"

  error:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["/var/log/nginx/*.error.log", "/var/log/nginx/*.error.log.1"]
    prospector:
      fields.class: "m-nginxerr"
      fields.env: "live"

filebeat.prospectors:


- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/squid/*.log
  fields.class: "m-squid"
  fields.env: "live"

setup.template.name: "m-fb"
setup.template.pattern: "m-fb-*"
setup.dashboards.index: "m-fb-*"

setup.dashboards.enabled: "false"

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["logstash-backend.foo.bar.com:9201"]
  index: 'm-fb-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}'
  indices:
    - index: "m-fb-nginxacc-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-nginxacc"

    - index: "m-fb-nginxerr-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-nginxerr"

    - index: "m-fb-m-app-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-app"

    - index: "m-fb-m-gc-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-gc"

    - index: "m-fb-m-deployment-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-deployment"

    - index: "m-fb-s3-backup-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-s3-backup"

    - index: "m-fb-m-squid-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-squid"

    - index: "m-fb-m-search-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-search"

    - index: "m-fb-m-img-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-img"

    - index: "m-fb-m-syslog-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-syslog"

    - index: "m-fb-m-nagios-%{+yyyy}"
      when.equals:
        fields.class: "m-nagios"

  protocol: "https"
  username: "user"
  password: "pass"
```

Do you have this problem or some idea for a solution to deal with this?

Comment: post you filebeat config - what logs is it processing? - what log level is that log set to?

Comment: It is processing nginx logs and it is heavy. I have added config to question.

Comment: What does the logs say ?